# Continuing issues with "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" using MVC3 EF4.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I posted this question previously and it explains what I'm doing pretty thoroughly:
[ASP.NET MVC3 and Entity Framework v4.1 with error An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12117072/asp-net-mvc3-and-entity-framework-v4-1-with-error-an-entity-object-cannot-be-ref)

The problem is that this issue has resurfaced several times with the mini-cart, lost cart, checkout page, etc after I fixed this particular problem in the question above. The further issues have been related to this, but not necessarily easy to identify and took a considerable amount of time to troubleshoot, find, and fix.  Rather than post my most current specific issue I'd rather find out if I'm doing something wrong in general.  Either by storing the cart, which is an entity, in a Session, or a better way to detach it (detach method shown below), or is there an easier way to debug these types of issues?  Here is an update to my detach method:

```
    public void DetachCart(Cart cart)
    {
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        if (cart.Customer != null)
        { objectContext.Detach(cart.Customer); }
        if (cart.ShipFromAddress != null)
        {
            var shipFromAddress = cart.ShipFromAddress;
            objectContext.Detach(cart.ShipFromAddress);
            cart.ShipFromAddress = shipFromAddress;
        }
        if (cart.ShipToAddress != null)
        {
            var shipToAddress = cart.ShipToAddress;
            objectContext.Detach(cart.ShipToAddress);
            cart.ShipToAddress = shipToAddress;
        }
        if (cart.Lines != null && cart.Lines.Count > 0)
        {
            List<CartLine> lines = new List<CartLine>();
            foreach (var item in cart.Lines.ToList())
            { 
                objectContext.Detach(item);
                lines.Add(item);
            }
            cart.Lines = lines;
        }
        objectContext.Detach(cart);
    }
```

Thank you for any insight you could provide me on this issue.  It's been a long painful road with this one.

**UPDATE**
It seems that a lot of my trouble stems from the fact that `CartModelBinder` leaves the cart in the attached state rather than the detached state.  By changing that it has eliminated my current issue and removed several places where I had to detach to avoid this issue.  However, my question "is there an easier way to detach all, or a way to debug/track these issues" still stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one solution - don't use entities in your views or model binders. Use view models and convert them to entities only when you are going save data to the database. It can make your application more complex but it will save you a great amount of time when troubleshooting issues with leaked contexts, attaching and detaching.

Comment: The complexity of the Cart entity lead me to avoid trying to copy back and fourth between various view models.  It would seem that wasn't a great decision. Although with the UPDATE I posted I think I'm OK for now.  Thanks Ladislav, this will certainly help me with future projects.